# setlocale não está funcionando no PHP

Tags: php, ubuntu

Estou seguindo os principais padrões para obedecer o formato **UTF-8**. Então, acima de todo o código da minha aplicação consta o seguinte.

```
/** Define a timezone padrão */
date_default_timezone_set( 'America/Sao_Paulo' );
/** Define o local */
setlocale( LC_ALL, 'pt_BR.utf8', 'pt_BR.utf8', 'pt_BR.utf8', 'portuguese' );

/** Habilita o encoding para UTF-8 */
mb_internal_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
mb_http_output( 'UTF-8' );
mb_regex_encoding( 'UTF-8' );
```

Mais tarde em uma das minhas funções, coleto a data do banco de dados e imprimo ela em formato por extenso, nos seguintes procedimentos:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->date );
echo $date->format('d \d\e M \d\e Y');
```

Ao invés de imprimir:

```
29 de Maio de 2017
```

Está imprimindo:

```
29 de May de 2017
```

Para me certificar que o locale **pt_BR** está instalado no **Ubuntu Server**, executei o seguinte comando **locale -a** e obtive o resultado:

```
C
C.utf8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
pt_BR.utf8
```

Possuo o **PHP 7.1** e **Ubuntu Server 14.04.5 LTS**. O que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: Não sei se é o caso, mas percebi que o PHP 7.1 está com bug nas datas (pelo menos pra mim). No meu programa eu setava a data e ele saia sempre com 3 horas a mais, mesmo declarando no set_locale e no arquivo  de configuração que era fuso do Brasil. Fiz o downgrade para o 7.0 e resolveu meu problema

Comment: Esta configuração do setlocale está em todos os aquivos? Tente criar um arquivo e colocar o as definições em seguida utilize o date format (tudo em um mesmo aquivo). Veja se mesmo assim continua o problema.

Comment: @BrunoFolle fiz o downgrade para a versão 7.0 e deixei ela ativa no Apache, mas o problema persiste. O horário está correto, o problema está mesmo com a tradução do mês, por exemplo.

Comment: @MoisesGama já havia feito isso em um arquivo de teste separado e o problema persiste.

Comment: Certo, pelo que eu sei o setlocale precisa estar em uma sequencia certa. 
Tente fazer assim: `// DEFINE A LIGUAGEM COMO PT-BR E UTF8
 setlocale(LC_ALL, 'pt_BR', 'pt_BR.UTF-8', 'pt_BR.utf-8', 'portuguese');

 // DEFINE O LOCAL DA APLICAÇÃO COM SÃO PAULO/BRAZIL/AMERICA
 date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');

 $date = DateTime::createFromFormat ( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $this->date );
 echo $date->format('d \d\e M \d\e Y');`

Comment: @MoisesGama na verdade elas são propriedades independentes, por tanto a ordem não influência. Mas para testar, fiz a troca e o problema persistiu.

Comment: Você tem acesso root do servidor? Consegue dar comandos SSH?

Comment: Se sim, tente fazer estes comandos: Primeiro comando:
sudo locale-gen pt_BR.UTF-8

Segudo comando:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales

Comment: Depois reinicia o Apache: service apache2 restart

Comment: @MoisesGama como eu já disse em meu relato, o locale pt_BR.UTF-8 já está instalado e configurado no Ubuntu.

Comment: Certo, desculpe não tinha visto. Não sei como ajudar. Desejo boa sorte.

Comment: vc quer só traduzir a data? a função `date()` e classe `DateTime` não são afetadas pelo locale.

Comment: Tente alterar todo o `DateTime::createFromFormat` para `echo strftime('%d de %B de %Y', strtotime(date('Y-m-d')));`